# how do i intercept xmlhttprequest and do some api calls before request gets send

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

how do i intercept xmlhttprequest and do some verification or do some api call before request gets send

as i wanted to integrate logic for expiry of jwt,where i verify that is jwt got expired or not and if yes then call token api and set to local storage and then perform other api so user state would be persistent and i using xmlhttpsrequest

i dont know where to place logic on send or open

```
xhr.send = function(data) {
      const rsc = this.onreadystatechange;


      this.onreadystatechange = function() {


        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status >= 400 && this.status < 600) {
          let el = typeof this.response === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(this.response) : this.response;

        }

        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 401) {
          console.log('session destroyes')d

        } else if (rsc) {
          return rsc.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      };

      return send.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To restore a token after its expiration you need to consider several important things. For example, what will need to send again failed request. I can recommend you to use [my example code for implementation JWT with axios](https://gist.github.com/GTOsss/ac499402e7b7599b0504541951afd0af).

Comment: i know with axios but im struck with xmlhttprequest,my app works on xmlhttprequest